# How can I remove Synth-shell startup information on Ubuntu 22?

Tags: command-line

[image]

Hey. I am new to Ubuntu and I found this on YouTube, it is a good-looking shell actually.
But I do not like it when I start the terminal, it comes pretty late because of showing this info. I didn't find in their repository how to remove this feature.

Answer (score 0):

When you install synth-shell it automatically adds some commands in your `.bashrc` file (in /home/{your_user_name}/.bashrc).

The command that runs these information you mentioned is the one around `status`. In my case it looks something like this:

```bash
    ##-----------------------------------------------------
    ## status
    ## Added by synth-shell
    ## https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell/
    if [ -f /home/{myname}/.config/synth-shell/status.sh ]; then
        source /home/{myname}/.config/synth-shell/status.sh
    fi
```

**All you got to do to stop this is to remove this block of code**. If you want to avoid doing some mistake, just make a backup file before doing any updates in the `.bashrc` file (that file is very important and used by the system :P )